# how to display both the series value in plotoptions mouseover event

Tags: highcharts

Using tooltip formatter we can display both the series name and value but when same is done using the plotoptions event mouseover am not able to get the series name and value

Tooltip: [formatter](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/74/)

PlotOption:[Mousover](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/73/)

```
                            mouseOver: function () {
                            $.each(this, function (i, e) {
                            $reporting.html('x: ' + this.x + 'Category: ' + this.series.name + ', y: ' +Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.y)));
                                });
                        }
```

Comment: Please take look at console, which returns many errors, as I see this.series.name is undefined. Morever what is the purpose of looping on this object which is current serie (single)?

Comment: Yeah, if I remove the looping it works fine; I am able to get the series name. But how do I get both the series name and its value?

Comment: In this.series.chart.series you have all series. Then you can loop for this object.

Comment: if we use this.series.chart.series, am not able to fetch either the chart series names or series value!

Comment: Becuase values are not in series, but in points.Morever this.x in loop  on series, refering to serie, not point. So you can need to add varaible which will keep point value, and in loop only print var. http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/77/

Comment: Thank you Sebastian :-) It worked :-)

Comment: Ok so I will add it as post and mark it as answer for other visitiors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of using it in `mouseover`

```
mouseOver: function () {
                            console.log(this);
                            var series = this.series.chart.series,
                                x = this.x,
                                y = this.y,
                                output = 'x: ' + x + 'y: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(y));
                            //loop each serie
                            $.each(series, function (i, e) {

                                output += ' Category: ' + this.name;

                                if(i>0) {
                                    $.each(series[i].data,function(j,point){
                                        if(point.x === x) {
                                            output += ' y: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(y));
                                        }

                                    });
                                }


                            });

                            $reporting.html(output);
                        }
                    }
                },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/77